# Laravel usage of GroupBy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to group data in a table by `cat_id` and convert the result into JSON.

Table structure

```
id  name  cat_id   
1    A      2 
2    B      1    
3    C      2     
4    D      2    
5    E      3     
6    F      2      
7    G      1
```

Here is the code I tried

```
$posts = Posts::groupBy('cat_id')->get();

return $posts->toJson();
```

Result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1", //cat_id
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": "2", //user id
                "s": "B"  //name
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "s": "G"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2", //cat id
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "A"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "C"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "s": "D"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "s": "F"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I'm getting `Call to a member function toJson() on a non-object`. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting result without toJson ?

Comment: @AnandPatel I'm getting results but not as I expected. There's clearly something wrong with the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `groupBy` doesn't work like this. It's more like SQLs `GROUP BY` (actually that's what it does in the background...)

I assume your error comes from the fact that it doesn't know what to do with `name` and `id` because you always need aggregate fields with `GROUP BY`.

Now here's how you can achieve your goal. I assume you have set up the relation between `Category` and `Post`. somewhat like this:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'cat_id');
    }
}
```

Then you are able to do:

```
$categories = Category::with('posts')->get();
```

And you get all the categories containing its `posts`. `toJson()` should work without a problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

@lukasgeiter suggested right thing to do, however there's another way to go too. Depending on your needs you can choose the one for you:

```
$posts = Pots::all(); // fetch from the DB

$groupedByCat = $posts->groupBy('cat_id'); // call group by on the collection
```

Result will look like this:

```
{
  "1":  // cat_id
    [
      {
         "id": "5"  // post data
         ...
      },
      ...
    ],
  "2":
    ...
}
```